# Queries and procedures in oracle

Tags: oracle

Is describe an inbuilt procedure? if not then what is it?
How can we call describe in odp.net and fetch the values returned by it.
I want to fetch the table returned by describe command and show it in a browser using gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Describe](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm) is a command restricted to SQL*Plus environment. You can't use it ODP.net or anywhere else except SQL*Plus.

If you want to emulate what Desc does, you probably should query [all_objects/user_objects](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn26146.htm#REFRN26146) view, find out the type of the object and fetch the relevent information from [other user_* metadata views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21644/systemtables.htm#TTSYS417)

Comment: Can you tell me any way of getting the metadata that is showed by describe in asp.net